# It's no any response after starting debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

According to the instruction: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw, .vscode files are set. Then, I add the MinGW64 path to the system path. But, when I start debugging, VS Code hangs and no finish, I also scan the Console by the steps: **Help->Toggle Developer Tools**, and the Console displays the following error, and I don't know how to solve.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qahe6.png)

The followings are my source code and both JSON files:

```cpp
// source code file
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

```
// launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-7.2.0-win32-sjlj-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
// tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-7.2.0-win32-sjlj-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-7.2.0-win32-sjlj-rt_v5-rev1\\mingw32\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: try to install MinGW in a directory without spaces in the path

Comment: When you post questions regarding code, you should always include a tag for the language you are working in. I've added the `C++` tag for you.

Comment: Thank you for dong that for me

Comment: @rioV8；I just install MinGW-w64, but I have replaced VS Code 64bit with VS Code 32bit, and it can successfully do it.